# Fix code c++ code highlighting in sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I would like to copy the C++ code highlighting from sublime into a word document.

I installed the package https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight/

I have the following text:

[image]

When I ask to view as RTF
I get:

[image]

Where the highlighting is no longer consistent. Is there any way to fix this?

Additionally, is it possible to copy the native syntax (first image) into rtf?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

From the readme of the SublimeHighlight package you are using (emphasis mine):

> This SublimeText2 package allows to highlight & export currently edited code to HTML or RTF **using Pygments**.

So this package will not help to have syntax highlighting like ST.

Sublime Text has included a command to copy the selected text as HTML since build 4092 (November 2020). (Edit menu -> Copy as HTML)

If you *really* need Rich Text Format instead, you could potentially look for a HTML -> RTF converter, but if you just want formatted text to paste into another application, then this does the job - I just pasted it into LibreOffice Writer for example, and it matched the ST highlighting exactly, as expected.

Comment: thanks for the reply! That is a very good feature. However, it does not copy my tabs when I paste into libreOffice :/ do you know why?

Comment: Although it works when I copy and paste into google docs...